# UISegmentedControl - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a little difficulty with the UISegmentedControl and can't find what is causing this issue.

The problem is the segmentChange method completely ignores the `else if` statement and just calls the poundValueSelected method.

ViewController1 is the child class and the viewController is the parent class.

Why is this happening?

#### ViewController1:

```
 [self.productCoreDetailView.segement addTarget:self.productViewController action:@selector(segmentChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

View Controller:

```
-(void)segmentChange{

if (self.productCoreDetailView.segement.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ) {
    [self poundValueSelected];

} else if (self.productCoreDetailView.segement.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    [self euroValueSelected];

}
```

Picture of the segment control:

[Segment Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBZT4.png)

Comment: try printing the selectedSegmentIndex value before if statement, to check what is its value

Comment: @user1000 I printed selectedSegmentIndex before , during and after the if statement and no matter what I click on the index is always 0.

Comment: can you show the picture of your segment control

Comment: @user1000 I've added it to the OP

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not sending the sender of this action that is your segment control, so try this code:

```
[self.productCoreDetailView.segement addTarget:self.productViewController action:@selector(segmentChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)segmentChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender{

    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ) {
         [self poundValueSelected];

    } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
         [self euroValueSelected];

    }
 }
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you so much